# How to add a where clause to this Entity Framework Linq statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework

I have set up EF 4.3 using a generic respository/uow pattern.

A typical method looks like this:

```
using (var uow = new UnitOfWork(ConnectionString.PaydayLenders))
{
    var r = new CrudRepo<Tier>(uow.Context);
    return r.Find()
    .Include("CommissionTiers.MatchService.Provider")
    .ToList();
}
```

As you can see, I also include other tables in the fetch using navigation properties.

In this example, a Tier has many CommissionTiers, CommissionTiers has a MatchService and MatchService has a provider.

What I want to be able to do is select where CommissionTier.Status = 1 and Provider = 1. Is there a way this can be incorporated into this statement/method?

Comment: Include is just for eager loading. are you sure you need it?

Comment: EF is much more mockable, that linq2sql was, I would question the reason why generic repository/uow is used, it adds unnecessary abstraction in most cases. On the other hand, if Find() returns IQueryable, you should be able to use navigation properties to perform what you need.

Comment: @omerschleifer - Well if I don't use it I'll still end up going back to the database for CommissionTiers etc

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Where(t => t.CommissionTiers
            .Any(ct => ct.Status == 1 && ct.MatchService.Provider == 1))
```

Because you have navigation properties in place there is no need for an explicit join in your LINQ statement.

Comment: Should be `Where( t => t.CommissionTier.Any( ...`

Comment: @DanielHilgarth - Not quite having the desired result. When I flag the provider status only the last tier of the selected provider is removed rather than all 3 tiers.

Comment: @dotnetnoob: That would be a new question I guess. This question doesn't contain a single word about removing something, let alone code that shows how you are trying to achieve this.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Join to get your required functionality.